# Скорость интернета ip.mail.ru (не отображается результат в html разметке)

Tags: c#, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Проблема следующая - захожу на http://ip.mail.ru/ , в веббраузере нажимаю кнопку "Измерить скорость".

Измерение скорости проходит успешно.

Данные отображаются в браузере:

[image]

Но при просмотре html кода страницы никак не могу найти эти данные. Сам я в JavaScript не разбираюсь, просьба подсказать как вытащить их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После измерения заполняется блок данных, в коде он такой:

```
<div id="status">
  <div id="download-speed">Скорость скачивания: <b>XXXXX.XX</b> Кбит/с </div>
  <div id="upload-speed">Скорость закачки: <b>XXXX.XX</b> Кбит/с </div>
</div>
```

X - цифра.
Парсить можно как хочешь, JS может так:

```
var downlSpeed = +document.querySelector('#download-speed b').innerHTML;
```

А увидеть ты не может, видимо, из-за того, что ты смотришь в сорцы страницы, а надо смотреть в DOM, ибо в сорцах пусто, заполняются данные о скорости потом через JS.
Такое легко покажет любой инспектор, например стандартный Chrome или Opera (по мне лучше и не надо).